# How can i extract html and put it into a div?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to grab some simple html and put into another DIV, but all i get back is `[object HTMLDivElement]`, What am i doing wrong here?

```js
this.inner = document.querySelector('div[data-v="1"]')
this.tail = document.querySelector('[data-tail]')
this.tail.innerHTML = this.inner
```

```html
<div data-tail></div>
<div data-v="1">some content</div>
```

Comment: My bad, It should be appendChild, not innerHTML in order to work. Someone can delete this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP asked for it in a comment

Comment: plus you are doing something odd with `this` that by pure chance happens to refer to the global `window` object and so doing those assignments you happen to declare variables (`tail`) with the value of an `HTMLElement` returned by `querySelector`.

Answer (score 3):

Add `.innerHTML` to get the content.

`document.querySelector('div[data-v="1"]')` refers to the object

```js
this.inner = document.querySelector('div[data-v="1"]').innerHTML
this.tail = document.querySelector('[data-tail]')
this.tail.innerHTML = this.inner
```

```html
<div data-tail></div>
<div data-v="1">some content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this documentation [first](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.
You just have to use innerHTML properly

```
this.inner = document.querySelector('div[data-v="1"]');
this.tail = document.querySelector('[data-tail]');
this.tail.innerHTML = this.inner.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it like this

```js
this.tail.innerHTML = this.inner.innerHTML
```

obviously you can not assign a ElementNode as HTML string.